# Do mirrors have fresnel?

Tags: materials, effects

I hear people say everything has fresnel which means the smaller the angle is that you look at an object, the less reflective it is.

I was wondering if this applies to mirrors.

Comment: If they do, I think the effect would be negligible so it wouldn't even be worth adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically speaking - that means if we are talking about a 100% reflective material - I'd say no.

In reality there is no material that has 100% reflectivity and of course it depends on the materials. If you have a highly polished chrome ball, the fresnel effect would be much lower than that of a normal glass mirror, that has only one side coated with aluminum, sliver or gold.

But in any case, the reflections on a highly reflective surface would surpass every possible Fresnel effect to a point where you wouldn't notice it anymore.

Comment: When trying to create an endless reflection by putting 2 mirrors opposite of each other eventually the reflection turns kinda green, does this have anything to do with fresnel?

Comment: @RyadShaanbi - It's more likely the material itself that is responsible for the effect. The main component for the most common glass variant is sand, which also contains iron oxide. This iron oxide filters the red component of the light, thus leaving the green and blue component of the light (which is also why most glass panes appear to be green at the edges). Everything visible works due to light reflection. An image reflection between two mirrors becomes greener and darker between each reflection, because each reflection loses more of the red component of the light rays.